# How do I get route values from inside a View Component controller in .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a View Component in `_Layout.cshtml`. My application has a route of `/home/{id}`. How can I get the `id` value in my URL route from the View Component controller?

```
public class LayoutViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        //how do I get the value of {id} here?

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want view to go and get the required parameter from query string by itself. It could strict the usage of the view.

Instead, you could pass `Id` from parent.

```
// Parent's Action Method
public IActionResult ParentActionMethod(int id)
{
    // You could use strongly typed model
    ViewBag.Id = 1;
    return View(); 
}    

// Parent's View
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Layout", new { Id = ViewBag.Id })

// View Component
public class LayoutViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int id = 10)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```